# Creating a bash script to ssh to a different system and run a command

Tags: linux, bash, loops, ssh, optional-parameters

first time on here, and very beginner when it comes to scripting. I am trying to create a script with options that allow me to ssh onto another system and then after on the other system perform a command. Here is what I have:

```
usage(){
    echo "./clu_com <FE ip addr> <option>"
    echo ""
    echo "Options are:"
    echo "  -s | --ssh )    Run all of the ssh options"
    echo "  -g | --get )    Run all of the get options"
    echo "  -p | --put )    Run all of the put options"
    echo "  -h | --help )   Bring up this menu"
    echo ""
}

cssh(){

    ssh $2 '[ssh-command]'

}

cget(){

    ssh $2 '[get-command]'
}

cput(){

    ssh $2 '[put-command]'
}

if [ "$#" != 2 ]; then
    usage
else
    while [ "$1" != "" ]; do
    case $1 in
            -g | --get )    cget
                            ;;
            -s | --ssh )    cssh
                            ;;
            -p | --put )    cput
                            ;;
            -h | --help )   usage
                            exit
                            ;;
            * )             echo "Invalid"
                            usage
                            exit
                            ;;
    esac
done
fi
```

As of right now all I have it doing is the basic -h command where it just shows the menu of options for each of the commands. The commands are already hard coded calls I am trying to use after I ssh into the system. Whenever I run this code I continuously get the usage for ssh, which I assume is due to my loop format. Not sure what is wrong though. Just looking for some input please.

Comment: So there has to be something wrong with my loop because even if I just enter in the ipaddr of the system I'm trying to get into, and then try to exit it automatically just ssh's me right back into it. So the loop is constantly running if I throw an exit after cssh it seems to allow me to exit without sshing back into the node automatically..

Comment: Please include a sample invocation and the result you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's ask [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) as suggested by the [bash tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info):

```
$ shellcheck yourscript
In yourscript line 12:
cssh(){
^-- SC2120: cssh references arguments, but none are ever passed.

In yourscript line 35:
 -s | --ssh ) cssh
              ^-- SC2119: Use cssh "$@" if function's $1 should mean script's $1.
...
```

And there you go. You're using `$2` in your functions, but in a function, `$2` means the argument to the function and not the argument to your script.

I suggest you pass just the hostname as an argument to your functions, and then use `"$1"` to reference it.

As for your infinite loop, I suggest you replace your `while [ "$1" != "" ]` with an `if [ "$1" != "" ]`. It doesn't look like you intend to handle multiple arguments anyways.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! I added a variable IP=$2 and now call $IP when I'm looking for the ipaddr input. I also changed my while-do statement to an if-then statement, so the script no longer loops. Thank you again for the help! :)